# .mpl extension in URL : Perl related technology?

Tags: perl, template-engine, mason

I've seen a company using this kind of URLs `http://www.foob.ar/cgi-perl/bar.mpl`. It seems they use Perl in the back-end, but I would like to know which technology (framework, modules, etc.) is supposed to be involved by the `.mpl` extension ?

I believe it would be [Mason template engine](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mason) but can't find a confirmation.

Comment: You can configure your webserver to handle the .mpl files with any interpreter.

Comment: @choroba, ok, but it is supposed to make sense. Why would you configure it to use .mpl if you use .php?

Comment: Security through obscurity, maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a MASON non top level module/script.

See this: http://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Mason::Admin

and this: http://www.masonhq.com/htmlmason/wiki/FAQ:ServerConfiguration

> Unlike many templating systems, Mason comes with no obvious filenaming standards. While this flexibility was initially considered an advantage, in retrospect it has led to the proliferation of a million different component extensions (.m, .mc, .mhtml, .mcomp, ...) and has made it more difficult for users to share components and configuration.
>
> The Mason team now recommends a filenaming scheme with extensions like
>   .html, .txt, .pl for top-level components, and .mhtml, .mtxt, **.mpl** for
>   internal (non-top-level) components. See
>   http://www.masonhq.com/docs/manual/Admin.html#controlling_access_via_filename_#controlling_access_via_filename_
>   for justification and configuration examples.